# python requests read from file status_code wrong

Tags: python, file, http, status

trying to read a file with urls and extract the status_code with python requests module.

this does not work, or gives me a wrong status code:

```
import requests

f = open('urls.txt','r')

for line in f:
  r =  requests.head(line)
  print r.status_code

  if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    print "ok";
```

but if I do it manually (without file read) it works.

```
import requests

r =  requests.head('https://encrypted.google.com/')
print r.status_code

if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
  print "ok";
```

Comment: `for line in f` keeps the trailing `\n`, so you might want to use line[:-1] for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `line.strip()` before making the `head` call. There is a possibility that the carriage return and/or line feed characters are part of the line you just read.

Like this:

```
for line in f:
    r =  requests.head(line.strip())
    print r.status_code
```